# Response structure for web service in C#

Tags: c#, web-services

I have my class structure for response as below:

```
   /// <remarks/>
    public  System.Collections.Generic.List<PaymentMethods> DisallowedPaymentMethods
    {
        get
        {
            return this.disallowedPaymentMethodsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.disallowedPaymentMethodsField = value;
        }
    }

   [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.18408")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://blcorp.net/PaymentInfoInquiryService")]
public partial class PaymentMethods
{

    private string paymentMethodField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string PaymentMethod
    {
        get
        {
            return this.paymentMethodField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.paymentMethodField = value;
        }
    }
 }
```

It's creating response as below

```
 <DisallowedPaymentMethods>
           <PaymentMethods>
              <PaymentMethod>CreditCard</PaymentMethod>
           </PaymentMethods>
           <PaymentMethods>
              <PaymentMethod>OnlineCheck</PaymentMethod>
           </PaymentMethods>
        </DisallowedPaymentMethods>
```

but I want response to be shown as below

```
     <DisallowedPaymentMethods>
              <PaymentMethod>CreditCard</PaymentMethod>
              <PaymentMethod>OnlineCheck</PaymentMethod>
        </DisallowedPaymentMethods>
```

How to create my response class to generate appropriate response structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Visual Studio, the easiest way to get a start is to copy the response as you want it into the clipboard, then use the "Paste XML as Classes" feature under the Edit => Paste Special menu.

- [Generate Class From JSON or XML in Visual Studio](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pranayamr/generate-class-from-json-xml-in-visual-studio/) from C-Sharp Corner
- [Generating Data Type Classes from XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/generating-data-type-classes-from-xml) from Microsoft Documentation

If you're not using Visual Studio, you can also try [Xml2Csharp.com](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your return type to this and populating as appropriate:

```
public  System.Collections.Generic.List<PaymentMethod> DisallowedPaymentMethods
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class structure, without decorations indicating otherwise, dictates what your serialized response is.  I think you class structure is a bit off.